# How to make associations work in built and unsaved objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have something like:

```
@order = Order.new(status: :pending)

@item  = @order.items.build(title: "Shirt")
```

When I try to call `@item.order`, I get an error not found, I guess it's because it's still unsaved to the DB, but how can make it point to the built object without saving any of the objects?

```
@item.order # Not Found - Tries to fetch from the DB
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make this work you have to tell the `order` association of your item model that it is the *inverse* of your `items` association or you order model and vice versa:

Like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :items
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, inverse_of: :order
end
```

That way your associations will be set up correctly even before saving to the database.

**EDIT:** If you don't want this you can always assign the association explicitly:

```
@item = @order.items.build(title: "Shirt")
@item.order = @order
```

or in one line:

```
@item = @order.items.build(title: "Shirt", order: @order)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, is there another way without touching the models themselves? so that I only apply this when I want?

Answer (score 3):

I tested this in Rails 4.0.1 and it looks like using `inverse_of` is no longer needed as the associations are inferred properly. It was addressed in this commit: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9522

It is worth noting that there is still no solution for `has_many through:` relationships at this time.

Comment: Is there still no solution for `has_many through:`? I just stumbled upon it and couldn't believe it.

Comment: You can use association callback and handle the in-memory association yourself, that is the only way I know of right now.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `@order` haven't got an ID yet. So when calling `@order.items.build` the item has an `nil` in `order_id` field and thus cannot found the order you want.

I suggest you use the [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) feature to save some associated records together.